# cURL over http/sock proxy with authentication

Tags: php, authentication, curl, proxy

I have problem with scraping data over proxy which use authentication. Proxy is online, its private and it work very fast from browser.

However proxy requires authentication and i just cant think of why this simple script doesnt work?!

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxyIP:proxyPORT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,"username:password");

    $result = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
?>
```

I have tried to set CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH with any valid value and it is same.. Any suggestion?

Comment: were you able to solve the issue, the answers mentioned doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPROXYTYPE) to tell curl which type of proxy you're using, as it will otherwise assume default type which is HTTP...

Answer (score 0):

Try **this** :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxyIP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 'proxyPORT');
```

instead of **this** :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxyIP:proxyPORT");
```